# Is there a way to connect to Zonky from outside?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, junit

I recently added Zonky for embedded postgres to legacy project that had no dnit tests at all.
I have a standard config:

```
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase(
        beanName = "myDatasource",
        type = AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase.DatabaseType.POSTGRES,
        provider = AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase.DatabaseProvider.ZONKY
)
```

Unfortunately, it turns out the app has second data source, which is `PGSimpleDataSource` defined from the code, with the same host, port, etc. passed in `application.yml` as the `myDatasource`.

Is there a way to access Zonky from outside, so I could pass these values without changing the old code? The reason behind it is the `myDatasource` is the "main" datasource for app, but the second one is in fact a list of multiple different datasources, not only this one.